# Github SQL Server installation

Tags: sql-server, d3.js, github

I am new to github I understand it is aversion control repository for collaborative software development. I wish to however explore that can we also install software such as SQL Server or java in github repository so that it provides a complete platform. Actually I have developed a software tool that uses HTML5 D3 and SQL Server I want it to upload to a Github repository so that other can see a live demo. I'm not sure how to do this - please comment

Comment: Github is a **source-code** repository - you upload **source code** to it. It's **not** a demo platform where you would show off your code as it runs - for that, you need other platforms ...

Comment: If you didn't had SQL, I'd say that what you want is a gist: https://gist.github.com/ Just set up a gist with your HTML (named `index`), JavaScript, CSV, JSON and whatever. After that, you'll got a URL for your gist. Then, change the `gist.github.com` in the URL for `bl.ocks.org`. That's it, you have a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Github will only host the source code itself and static html pages. Nothing is actually executed there. Basically a folder on a computer. Passive. You would need to use a cloud platform like gcp or aws to do what you are describing.